# Will the tx fees of old contracts be greater or smaller than those of new contracts in ETH 2.0?

Tags: gas, contract-invocation, gas-price, fees, eth-2.0

Will contracts that currently exist cost more or less to interact with after the ETH 2.0 upgrade? What about old contracts that call a new contract, or new contracts that call an old contract?

Will the difference (if any) be due to the amount of gas consumed, or due to economic reasons? (e.g. the shard with the old chain may have a greater transaction volume and therefore a higher average gas price)